# Intertwined classes in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I find myself with a layout problem. I have an instance method that returns an instance of another class, but to do so requires the first instance. For example:

```
class bar:
    def __init__(self, barvalue, foo_instance, flag, x):
         # munge barvalue based on foo_instance, flag and x
         self._data = barvalue 

class foo(basefoo):
    def __init__(self, value, flag, x):
        self._data=value  # same as basefoo
        if flag:
             self._extra=x  #absent in basefoo
        innervalue=value
        self.munged = bar(innervalue, self, flag, x)
```

The `self.munged = bar(value, self, x, y)` seems a bit hackish, so I would like to check if this the cleanest way.

## Nested class tangent

If need be, bar could be made a sub-class [*sic.* nested class] of foo — the idea of `bar(basefoo(value),barvalue, flag, x)` is nice, but I could write a class method to covert basefoo to a foo.

But I am not sure what I would gain. In a previous edit I misunderstood how the nested class would work. It turns out the inner class (bar) does not receive the self form `self.bar`. I thought it was because `__new__` gets called before `__init__`, but this is not the case as `__new__` does not receive the self form `self.bar`. but this is a topic for another question.

```
class foo(basefoo):
    class bar:
         def __init__(self, barvalue, foo_instance, flag, x):
              # munge barvalue based on foo_instance, flag and x
              self._data = barvalue 
    def __init__(self, value, flag, x):
        self._data=value  # same as basefoo
        if flag:
             self._extra=x  #absent in basefoo
        innervalue=value
        self.munged = self.bar(innervalue, self)
        #NOT self.munged = self.bar(innervalue)
```

and force the user to covert a basefoo object to a foo object to get bar if need be? Is this the right line of thought?

## Concern

This is the second time I have found myself writing this layout —the other turned messy [see GitHub repo of messy code](https://github.com/matteoferla/DnD-battler). So I don't want to repeat the messiness.

So, is this the best way or is there a clever trick?

Also, does this situation have a name? My google-fu failed me.

Comment: Can you expand further with example of where it gets messy? I'm not yet clear what you actually do with these 2 classes.

Comment: `self.munged = A(value, self)` with the self inside the call makes me think I am missing something.

Comment: `A = bar` and `B = foo`, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry `self.munged = bar(value, self)`. I'll fix the code.

Comment: I smell possible circular reference problems... If you want to have pair of objects refering to each other, take a look at [`weakref` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html).

Comment: Even after the edit I can't understand what the question is about :(

Comment: It is my fault. I went on a tangent about nested classes, which still generates the syntax that is weirding me out (`self.munged = self.bar(innervalue, self)`) —it is not clear why the outer class's self is not passed to the inner one, but that is besides the point.
The fact that the problem is unclear is an answer itself. There is nothing wrong with the code, which answers my question.

Comment: Actually your code does nothing, that's why it's hard to judge

Comment: What does `bar` actually do with `foo_instance`? I see nothing inherently wrong with an object passing itself to an external function, even if that external function happens to be the constructor for another class, and it's difficult to tell whether circular references are likely to become a problem. Can you try and explain how/why your past code became messy, as people may not have time to read/analyse your D&D game. More context would also help suggest cleaner solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I thought a generalisation of my [code](https://github.com/matteoferla/mutagenesis/blob/master/Mutant.py) would be simpler, for the question, namely whether the convoluted `self.munged = self.bar(innervalue, self)` was the best way to do it.

And actually, you have answered my question.

There is "nothing inherently wrong with an object passing itself to an external function, even if that external function happens to be the constructor for another class, " but circular references could be a problem, which is solvable with the `weakref module`.